# Compress latest kernel with upx

Tags: linux, kernel, compression, upx

I'm just curious, how to compress latest (2.6.32 at time of writing) kernel using UPX?

It worked well for older kernels but now repacked with UPX kernel fails to boot, standard compression methods (gzip, bzip2, lzma) work fine though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be related with some config options from kernel.

> $ zcat /proc/config.gz | grep -i lzma
>
> > CONFIG_HAVE_KERNEL_LZMA=y
> >
> > CONFIG_DECOMPRESS_LZMA=y

Check your config in General Setup tab from kernel